# How to jump to matching (double or single) quote of a quoted string?

Tags: motion, quote

When cursor on one quote symbol, how to jump to the pairing quote?

Comment: I don't have Emacs now to try, but I'd imagine `skip-syntax-forward` would do that.

Comment: I tried `(skip-syntax-forward "^\"")` which can jump to the next double quote symbol, but it doesn't skip escaped symbol, e.g., "string \" cannot be skipped?".

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>M-C-f</kbd> (or <kbd>M-C-right</kbd>) bound to `forward-sexp` should do that.

I suggest you try all well-known motion commands with the prefix `M-C-` instead of `C-`.

- <kbd>M-C-b</kbd> (or <kbd>M-C-left</kbd>) gives `backward-sexp`
- <kbd>M-C-u</kbd> (or <kbd>M-C-up</kbd>) gives `backward-up-list`
- <kbd>M-C-n</kbd> (or <kbd>M-C-down</kbd>) gives `forward-list`

Comment: You should also mention `backward-sexp` bound to `M-C-b`.

Comment: @Timm I thought it would be rather obvious that one tries the motion commands with prefix `M-C` instead of `C-` if one knows `M-C-f`. Okay -- I will mention it in the answer.

Comment: It seems that `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp` stop at whitespaces inside a quoted string?

Answer (score 2):

I always have trouble remembering the bindings for `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp`, and I wanted something that worked more like `%` does in Vim's command mode. At some point, I added this to my config (the docstring says parens but it works for any of sort of bracket or quote), and now I'm satisfied:

```
;;; PAREN-BOUNCE
;;;; originally ganked from <http://elfs.livejournal.com/1216037.html>
(defun genehack/paren-bounce ()
  "Bounce from one paren to the matching paren."
  (interactive)
  (let ((prev-char (char-to-string (preceding-char)))
        (next-char (char-to-string (following-char))))
    (cond ((string-match "[[{(<\"']" next-char) (forward-sexp 1))
          ((string-match "[\]})>\"']" prev-char) (backward-sexp 1))
          (t (error "%s" "Not an expression boundary.")))))

;;;; bindings
(global-set-key (kbd "C-%")        'genehack/paren-bounce)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-5")        'genehack/paren-bounce)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using smartparens package for all such purposes. Short introduction is here: https://ebzzry.io/en/emacs-pairs/ .

Comment: Please provide a complete answer in your post.  Link-only responses are okay for comments, but not for answers.

Comment: `sp-beginning-of-sexp` and `sp-end-of-sexp` are very close to what I want. I hope that they can be combined into one function (e.g., `sp-matching-sexp`) so that I only need to remember one keybinding.  Maybe I will try to write an elisp function.  Let me know if anyone did that before.  Thanks.

Comment: https://ebzzry.io/en/emacs-pairs/#keys

("C-M-f" . sp-forward-sexp)
("C-M-b" . sp-backward-sexp)

But you can set it different